# jquery countdown plugin problem

Tags: jquery, plugins, date, time, timer

I want to show jquery countdown timer, but want to show only minutes and seconds. it is fine i , can achieve by

`$('#defaultCountdown').countdown({ until: dt, format: 'YOWDHMS', significant: 2 });`

but it by default taking computer date time. I have picked the date and time from my database. and want to set to "dt" here. but it is not setting the date as i am using this code:

```
 $(function() {
            var totalTime = document.getElementById("testTime").value;
 var dt = new Date();
            dt.setDate(totalTime);
             $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({ until: dt, format: 'YOWDHMS', significant: 2 });


        });
```

this is my script. what should be the problem? I think setDate is for only date . where as i have value in "totalTime" ="5/12/2010 00:05:25 Pm" how to set full date to Date injavascript

Comment: countdown timer in reverse mode = stopwatch ?

Comment: no it was finger mistake. edited

Comment: Do you get any error messages? What the exact problem?

Comment: problem is i am unable to set date to "dt" here. also though i explicitly sett the minutes to "dt" here it is showing 00:00 on ui.in short Date object in javascript here using system date. want to set custom date

Comment: `$('#defaultCountdown').countdown({ until: new Date(dt), format: 'YOWDHMS', significant: 2 });` does it help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the way. It was too easy but i spent lot of time.I used this script:

```
        $(function() {
            var totalTime = document.getElementById("testTime").value; //get minutes value from code behind in hidden filed or use some other way to get value.

            var min = totalTime; 
            var sec = 00;
            $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({ until: '+' + min + 'm +' + sec + 's', format: 'YOWDHMS', significant: 2 });
 });
```

It is perfectly showing me minute-seconds countdown timer.

Answer (score 1):

```
"SELECT TIME_TO_SEC( TIMEDIFF(yourtable_field, NOW( ) ) ) AS clock FROM table "
```

change your timestamb in to seconds by above query. store this this time in some HTML element for

example :
add some hidden text field with id clock and value= `echo $clock` --in php

then it's simple

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var clocktime =$('#clock').val();

$('#countbox').countdown({

layout:'{mnn} : {snn}',
    timeSeparator: ':', 

until: +clocktime
});
</script>
```

Comment: this answer is the best solution for me. I'm using it now. Thanks mate!